# Implementation of LinkedList interface

Tags: java, linked-list

I want to add multiple elements using linked list interface.....My code is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LList 
{
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          Node node;

          Random rand = new Random();
          int Threshold = 10;
          long P,D,Du;

          LinkedList<Node> ll = new LinkedList<Node>();


          for(int i =1;i<=Threshold;i++)
          {  
              Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
              long m = c.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND);
              Du = rand.nextInt(4);
              P =   rand.nextInt(10)+1;
              D = Period + m;
                  node = new Node("T"+i, m, Du, P, D);
                          ll.add(node)
              System.out.println("The content of linklist is: " + ll);
              System.out.println("The size of linklist is: " + ll.size());
         } 



      }
    }
```

//Node Class

```
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class Node extends LinkedList
{

     long du;
     long p,Arr,d;
     String task;
     Node next;  

     public Node(String Task,long arr,long dur, long per,long d1)  
     { 
         task=Task;
         Arr = arr;
         du = dur;
         p = per;
         d = dl;
     }  

     public void displayNode()  
     {  
            System.out.print(task+","+Arr+","+du+","+p+","+d+"\n");

     }

}
```

OUTPUT:

The content of linklist is: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
The size of linklist is: 10

It is not displaying the values......m i implement this interface wrong?

Comment: What did you expect the output to be exactly?

Comment: did you use debug and tried to follow the code?

Comment: Where did you see such interface?

Comment: Besides: The output is correct. Node extends LinkedList, but the nodes do not have children, so their toString() will return "[]".

Answer (score 5):

The reason that your lists are not displaying is that you have not overridden the toString() interface in your Node class.

I'm also wondering if you realize that each instance of your `Node` class is actually a list.  So each instance has a a bunch of elements, some data fields and a link to another Node.  If you are really trying to implement a linked list from the ground up, you probably should not be extending `LinkedList`.

Comment: He did not, but Node extends LinkedList, which does so. What I do not get, why Node extends LinkedList in the first place.

Comment: @Fildor - I am aware of that.  He wanted to know why his list was not displaying as he expected ... and my answer gives the reason.  For the rest, I think he has simply made a mistake.

Comment: You are completely right. Wasn't meant offensive, just wanted to add the info. :)

Answer (score 1):

`Node` is the element of the list. It doesn't need to extend `LinkedList`. Furthermore,  override `toString` in class `Node` instead of using `diaplayNode`.

Comment: After removal of extends the output is The content of linklist is: [Node@190d11, Node@a90653, Node@de6ced, Node@c17164, Node@1fb8ee3, Node@61de33, Node@14318bb, Node@ca0b6, Node@10b30a7, Node@1a758cb]
The size of an linklist is: 10

Comment: I want the output like ::     [[T1 2 4 3 5],[T2 3 5 6 9]]...I hope now u all understand my problem

Comment: Just change your displayNode() method into ''public String toString()''and inside instead of writing to System.out return that string.